# How to load a different layout while you are initializing android service

Tags: android, splash-screen

I have an android service that takes a lot of time to initialize. I wanted to hide this by showing a splash screen while initializing it. please notice the initilization of service and showup of splash screen occurs at the same time, and when initialization ends, activity returns to normal layout. So please don't suggest having an independent splashactivity that shows the splash screen for some time and then start my main activity. The service is initialized in main activity so splash screen has to be done in main activity as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) for that. You will be under your main activity context while you be able to show splash screen in a fragment view.

Example from that attached link:

> For example, here's a subclass of Fragment that loads a layout from
>   the example_fragment.xml file:

```
public static class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

Please read the complete article before asking me any more questions.